# How to count and display array values in php

Tags: php

I have one object array data coming below way.

```
$rooms= Single room,Single room,Single room ;
```

Here i want to display data below format

```
3 X Single room
```

For example rooms coming below format

```
Single room, Double room , Single room
```

then i need to out put is

```
2x single room 
1x Double room
```

How to get like this ,Please tell me, i tried `array_count_values` and `array_unique` but not get result. Please any one know tell me

```
$str = rtrim(implode(",",explode("#", Single Room#DOuble Room#Single Room))); 
$ss= str_replace(' ','',$str); 
$ss1= str_replace(',',' ',$ss); 
$rooms = explode(' ', $ss1); 
//Count each occurence of values 
$countedValues = array_count_values($rooms); 
//Build strings from value and display them. 
foreach( $countedValues as $roomType=>$count ){ 
    echo $count . 'x ' . $roomType . '<br />'; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code so we can take it from there. Show us what your tried and we can help

Comment: Show us what you have try, and where you are stucked... nobody code for you

Comment: `$str = rtrim(implode(",",explode("#", Single Room#DOuble Room#Single Room)));
          $ss= str_replace(' ','',$str);
          $ss1= str_replace(',',' ',$ss);
          $rooms = explode(' ', $ss1);
          //Count each occurence of values
          $countedValues = array_count_values($rooms);
          //Build strings from value and display them.
          foreach( $countedValues as $roomType=>$count ){
           echo $count . 'x ' . $roomType . '<br />';
          }    `

Comment: Finally i got this result

Comment: In future please post code in your question. Nobody can read code in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you're using `array_count_values` because you haven't posted your code, please post your code in future. Below is a working example that gives your desired output.

```
<?php

$rooms = "Single room,Single room,Single room,Double room";
$rooms = explode(',', $rooms); // array of rooms
//Count each occurence of values
$countedValues = array_count_values($rooms);

//Build strings from value and display them.
foreach( $countedValues as $roomType=>$count ){
    echo $count . 'x ' . $roomType . '<br />';
}

?>
```

This gave me the output:

```
3x Single room
1x Double room
```

Please note that your question includes this:

```
$rooms= Single room,Single room,Single room ;
```

this is not a valid array format. You should use this instead:

```
$rooms = array("Single room","Single room","Single room");
```

Comment: sorry am getting string format data. Single room,Single room,Single room. what you are given code correct for array . but i have string

Comment: @Niru use [explode](http://php.net/explodeon) on the string to convert it into an Array.

Comment: Please tell me i have string  Single room,Single room,Single room . how can i do for this string

Comment: @PeterM Thank Q Sooooooo Much

Comment: **i did like this**  `$str = rtrim(implode(",",explode("#", Single Room#DOuble Room#Single Room))); $ss= str_replace(' ','',$str); $ss1= str_replace(',',' ',$ss); $rooms = explode(' ', $ss1); //Count each occurence of values $countedValues = array_count_values($rooms); //Build strings from value and display them. foreach( $countedValues as $roomType=>$count ){ echo $count . 'x ' . $roomType . '<br />'; }`